# do_patch can't find files

Tags: patch, yocto, bitbake

I am able to fetch, build and install some software from github, but when I add a patch to the recipe the patch fails on not being able to find the file.  I used devshell, (my vendor has spotty support for devtool).  I used git to create the patch.

```
python do_compile(){
    B = d.getVar("WORKDIR") # could not directly access ${WORKDIR} why?
    myStr = 'cd '+B+'/git/mytool1 && make'
    myStr = 'cd '+B+'/git/mytool2 && make'
}

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}/opt/alx
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/git/mytool1/app/tool1 ${D}/opt/alx
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/git/mytool2/mytool2 ${D}/opt/alx
}
```

somehow I think the /git/ is the issue?  Having a little difficulty figuring out where the do_patch happens in the directory tree.

can't find file to patch at input line 15
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:

line 15 is the first line after

```
   --- a/mytool1/mytool
   --- b/mytool2/mytool2
```

Comment: Why do you use `python do_compile` instead of `do_compile`? you should call `make` through `oe_runmake`, but default `do_compile` already calls it, so you don't need to override it. If you have two tools into your git repo, you can add a main Makefile that calls make for subdirectories, or create two recipes. `do_patch` will call patch from `${S}` (by default `${WORKDIR}`) path. Finally `do_install` should peak stuff from `${B}` build folder and `${B}` shouldn't be set to `${WORKDIR}` as it is a "staged" area.

Comment: Thanks for the help... My do_compile was taken from an example in a book, that indicated using ${WORKSPACE} directly and used cd and make as I did.  Seems like this is a bad example and I should use oe_runmake.  This is not my code and so for whatever reason doesn't come with a single Makefile.  The fetch is in a single call so it seems like tow recipes doesn't make sense.

Comment: (FINISHED COMMENT) Nayfe, thanks for the help... My do_compile was taken from an example in a book, that indicated using ${WORKSPACE} directly and used cd and make as I did.  Seems like this is a bad example and I should use oe_runmake at least.    This is not my code and so for whatever reason doesn't come with a single Makefile.  The fetch is in a single call so it seems like two recipes doesn't make sense.  Can I use oe_runmake on eg: ${B}/mytool1/mytool1 ?

Comment: What I mean is if you have two unrelated applications in same git repo, you can create two recipes with `same SRC_URI`, but then you set `S = "${WORKDIR}/git/app1"` in app1 recipe and `S = "${WORKDIR}/git/app2"` in app2 recipe.

Comment: you can use `S = "${WORKDIR}/git"` then some`do_compile(){  oe_runmake -C ${S}/app1 && oe_runmake -C ${S}/app2 }`

Comment: Nayfe- thanks.   I did as you said and it worked.  One weird example can sure drive you wrong.  I had to re-run devshell and create a new patch.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `python do_compile()` function by the following:

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/git" 

do_compile(){
    oe_runmake -C ${S}/mytool1 
    oe_runmake -C ${S}/mytool2
}
```